# Unable to run app using Next generation build system

Tags: nx.dev

Error while running app `nx serve frontend`

```
> nx run frontend:serve:development


 >  NX   RunStart

   
{
  "meta": {
    "nxCloudVersion": "latest"
  },
  "branch": null,
  "runGroup": "8d44d4811566fc991ad067785087e06ee8f245e0",
  "ciExecutionId": null,
  "ciExecutionEnv": "",
  "hashes": [
    "c7bb0f1dc0715bc179aaffff98f78c6ad7843ed55398dca6b34657f16db2193b"
  ]
}

RunStart duration: 391
[ info ]  found proxy configuration at D:\projects\my-apps\interview-prep\apps\frontend\proxy.conf.json
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'executor')
    at getNxContext (D:\projects\my-apps\interview-prep\node_modules\.pnpm\@nrwl+next@15.8.9_hiw5yk7bsnojr6hab6ukoqdfju\node_modules\@nrwl\next\plugins\with-nx.js:43:45)
    at D:\projects\my-apps\interview-prep\node_modules\.pnpm\@nrwl+next@15.8.9_hiw5yk7bsnojr6hab6ukoqdfju\node_modules\@nrwl\next\plugins\with-nx.js:104:106
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (D:\projects\my-apps\interview-prep\node_modules\.pnpm\tslib@2.5.0\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:164:62)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

 —————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————— 
 >  NX   Running target serve for project frontend failed

   Failed tasks:

   - frontend:serve:development

   Hint: run the command with --verbose for more details.

   View structured, searchable error logs at https://nx.app/runs/S2YWBKpNGH
```

Project.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/frontend",
  "projectType": "application",
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/next:build",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputPath}"],
      "defaultConfiguration": "production",
      "options": {
        "root": "apps/frontend",
        "outputPath": "dist/apps/frontend"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "development": {
          "outputPath": "apps/frontend"
        },
        "production": {}
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/next:server",
      "defaultConfiguration": "development",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "frontend:build",
        "dev": true,
        "proxyConfig": "apps/frontend/proxy.conf.json"
      },
      "configurations": {
        "development": {
          "buildTarget": "frontend:build:development",
          "dev": true
        },
        "production": {
          "buildTarget": "frontend:build:production",
          "dev": false
        }
      }
    },
    "export": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/next:export",
      "options": {
        "buildTarget": "frontend:build:production"
      }
    },
    "test": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/jest:jest",
      "outputs": ["{workspaceRoot}/coverage/{projectRoot}"],
      "options": {
        "jestConfig": "apps/frontend/jest.config.ts",
        "passWithNoTests": true
      },
      "configurations": {
        "ci": {
          "ci": true,
          "codeCoverage": true
        }
      }
    },
    "lint": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/linter:eslint",
      "outputs": ["{options.outputFile}"],
      "options": {
        "lintFilePatterns": ["apps/frontend/**/*.{ts,tsx,js,jsx}"]
      }
    }
  },
  "tags": []
}
```

It was working yesterday. Not sure what has changed. I am new to nx.